# Word Macro AutoOpen not running

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got a Word document that contains an AutoOpen macro. It works fine until I upload it to out intranet for people to download. When some users opens it from the intranet, it opens an embedded instance of word within IE, the doucment opens but the AutoOpen does not run. If they download the document, then open it, it work correctly.

If I open the document from the Intranet from my PC it works correctly. So I suspect there is a problem with their setup. I have looked at the security level in word and it is medium.

Any Ideas on how to get it to run AutoOpen when opening from an intranet site?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your clients' browser security settings. They might disallow execution of active content.